# How to make Divs independent

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function createDiv() {
  var yellowButton = document.getElementById("yellowColor");
  var newNote = document.createElement('div');


 document.getElementById('theText1').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
    newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('theText1').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(newNote);
    newNote.style.display = "inline-block";
    newNote.className = "segments";
  
  newNote.classList.add('draggable');
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    containment: "canvas"
  });

  newNote.classList.add('resizable');
  $('.resizable').resizable(); 

}


function genPDF() {
var doc = new jsPDF();
          var specialElementHandlers = {
         '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

         doc.fromHTML($('#canvas').html(), 15, 15, {
         'width': 170,
         'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');


}
```

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>

  .draggable {
    cursor: move;
  }

  .segments {
    display: block;
    border : 1px solid black;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
   font-weight: 200;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }

  #yellowNoteStyle {
    /*
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   margin: 10px;
   */
   display: block;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 200;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
  
  }
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">

<head>
<title> Minimal Cheatsheet Builder </title>
</head>
<left>
  <h1> cheat it - minimal cheatsheet builder</h1>
</left>

<style>
    .indent-1 {float: left;}
    .indent-1 section {width: 50%; float: left;}
</style>

<section class="indent-1">
    <!-- Section 1 --> 
    <section id="addnote">
    <div>
      <left>
        <form action="mainpage.php" method="post">
          <h3> Insert onto cheatsheet. </h3>
          <textarea id="textOfNote"></textarea>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <table style="display:none">
            <tr>
              <td> <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellowColor" /> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <div id="yellowNoteStyle"> </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>
          <br/>
        </form>
      </left>
    </div>

    <div id="create">
      <button onClick="createDiv()">Create Segment</button>
    </div>


    <div id="trash" style="width:50mm; height:50mm">
      <h3>trashcan</h3>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#trash" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.draggable.remove();
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <section>
        <div id="canvas" style="width: 297mm; height: 210mm"></div>

        
        <button id="gen" onClick="genPDF()">generate PDF</button>

    </section>
</section> 

<br>


<div id="yellowNote" style="display: none;">
  <div id="yellowNoteStyle" ></div>
    <p><span id='theText1'></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made a simple web application which allow you to creates dynamic divs

You can see how the app is looking here :
before resizing 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i50Cf.jpg
after resizing
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWkI9.jpg

when the create segment button is pressed, a new div is created beside the old divs

Theses dynamics divs add by this way can be dragged and resized by jQuery with the jQuery ui draggable and resizable method.

the draggable function works well, but not the resizable. It seem like the divs are dependents, and when you try to resize it, it depends of the size of the others dynamics divs.

```
function createDiv() {
  var yellowButton = document.getElementById("yellowColor");
  var newNote = document.createElement('div');


    document.getElementById('theText1').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
    newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('theText1').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(newNote);
    newNote.style.display = "inline-block";
    newNote.className = "segments";

  newNote.classList.add('draggable');
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    containment: "canvas"
  });

  newNote.classList.add('resizable');
  $('.resizable').resizable(); 

}
```

Comment: `newNote` is displayed as inline-block, while standard divs are displayed as `block`. Maybe this is affecting the resizability? (BTW, it would be easier to help debug your code if the HTML markup were included in the question as well.)

Answer (score 0):

why did you comment jquery ui css?. remove the comment and it will work.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

```js
function createDiv() {
  var yellowButton = document.getElementById("yellowColor");
  var newNote = document.createElement('div');


 document.getElementById('theText1').innerHTML = document.getElementById("textOfNote").value;
    newNote.innerHTML = document.getElementById('theText1').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("canvas").appendChild(newNote);
    newNote.style.display = "inline-block";
    newNote.className = "segments";
  
  newNote.classList.add('draggable');
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    containment: "canvas"
  });

  newNote.classList.add('resizable');
  $('.resizable').resizable(); 

}


function genPDF() {
var doc = new jsPDF();
          var specialElementHandlers = {
         '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

         doc.fromHTML($('#canvas').html(), 15, 15, {
         'width': 170,
         'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');


}
```

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://resources/demos/style.css">

  <style>

  .draggable {
    cursor: move;
  }

  .segments {
    display: block;
    border : 1px solid black;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
   font-weight: 200;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
  }

  #yellowNoteStyle {
    /*
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   margin: 10px;
   */
   display: block;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 200;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   white-space: pre-wrap;
  
  }
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">

<head>
<title> Minimal Cheatsheet Builder </title>
</head>
<left>
  <h1> cheat it - minimal cheatsheet builder</h1>
</left>

<style>
    .indent-1 {float: left;}
    .indent-1 section {width: 50%; float: left;}
</style>

<section class="indent-1">
    <!-- Section 1 --> 
    <section id="addnote">
    <div>
      <left>
        <form action="mainpage.php" method="post">
          <h3> Insert onto cheatsheet. </h3>
          <textarea id="textOfNote"></textarea>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <table style="display:none">
            <tr>
              <td> <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellowColor" /> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <div id="yellowNoteStyle"> </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>
          <br/>
        </form>
      </left>
    </div>

    <div id="create">
      <button onClick="createDiv()">Create Segment</button>
    </div>


    <div id="trash" style="width:50mm; height:50mm">
      <h3>trashcan</h3>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#trash" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.draggable.remove();
      }
    });
  } );
  </script>

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <section>
        <div id="canvas" style="width: 297mm; height: 210mm"></div>

        
        <button id="gen" onClick="genPDF()">generate PDF</button>

    </section>
</section> 

<br>


<div id="yellowNote" style="display: none;">
  <div id="yellowNoteStyle" ></div>
    <p><span id='theText1'></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```